# ofstream не создает файл несколько раз

Tags: c++

Запускаю программу, которая открывает и закрывает ofstream, файл создается, однако если я его мануально удаляю и запускаю программу снова - файл с тем же названием больше не создаётся, даже после рекомпиляции.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()

{

    unsigned userID = 0;
    std::string filename = "user_" + std::to_string(userID) + ".txt";
    std::ofstream userdata (filename);

    if(userdata.is_open())

    {

        userdata << "Text";
        userdata.close();

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Компилятор - g++ 7.5.0
IDE не пользуюсь, текстовый редактор - nano.

Comment: попробуйте использовать fstream для этого, но это вообще странно что он не создаётся)

Comment: Может он создается не там, где вы думаете? Проверьте все еще раз.

Comment: Дело в том, что файл создается в нужной мне папке, но как я и сказал после удаления и запуска программы снова файл с таким же названием больше не создаётся, проблема точно не в месте создания.

Comment: поставьте вместо ofstream fstream и проверьте будёт ли так же

Comment: Пробовал, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: тогда проблема в самом проекте, попробуйте пересоздать что-ли + еще зависит какой у вас редактор, там могуть быть разные пути к файликам

Comment: Ну тогда покажите код, который можно скомпилировать (см. [mcve]), и покажите лог консоли, в котором было бы видно, что сначала файла нет, после первого запуска он есть, а после удаления и второго запуска не появился.

Comment: Чудес не бывает, что-то вы не договариваете...

Comment: Если у вас редактор открыл файл, и вы файл удалили, то в файловой системе он находиться как зомби. Новый файл невозможно создать, пока вы редактор не закроете.

Comment: Обновил код и добавил информацию в описание. Так же стоит упомянуть что я писал и компилировал код в Windows Subsystem for Linux. Однако я попробовал перекомпилировать программу средствами Windows и ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в `else`-блок условного оператора вывод сообщения об ошибке открытия файла (что-то вроде `std::cerr << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;`) Возможно там будет что-то, что поможет разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в wsl(Windows Subsystem for Linux), которую я использовал для компиляции и запуска кода. Если код запускать и удалять файл в рамках одной оболочки, то проблемы не возникает. Я же запускал код в wsl под ubuntu, а удалял созданный файл средствами Windows, из-за чего в файловой системе linux он оставался, хоть и не был виден(созданные файлы открывались, и могли быть удалены, но не отображались в команде ls и проводнике Windows, после удаления "призрачных" файлов из файловой системы linux, новые одноименные файлы отображаются корректно)